# Process requests one by one in Jetty Embedded

Tags: java, web-services, jetty

I have a small web service that receives via `POST` a `JSON` with a set of strings, processes them and outputs the results in a `JSON` format.

The thing is, the processing is very resource heavy (CPU and Memory) so I want to be able to queue the requests and process them one by one (or two by two, etc).

First I created my server with a `QueuedThreadPool` like this:

```
QueuedThreadPool threadPool = new QueuedThreadPool(4, 1);
Server jettyServer = new Server(threadPool);
```

But this only limits the number of threads, and if one single thread makes multiple requests, the service crashes.

Next, I tried with a `LinkedBlockingQueue`. Like this:

```
LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>(2);
QueuedThreadPool threadPool = new QueuedThreadPool( 4, 1, 30000, queue);
Server jettyServer = new Server(threadPool);
```

Like this, it seems to work because the service only processes two sets of text at a time and does not crashes, but the problem is, the other requests are discarded and receive a `502 status code`. The server throws a `RejectedExecutionException` and continues the execution.

Is there a way to configure a queue of requests and process them one by one but not discarding the rest? Like that, queue the requests but limit the number of requests served at a time.

Answer (score 2):

Jetty does not have a 1 thread == 1 request model.

It is entirely possible for 1..n threads to be used over the lifetime of a single request/response exchange.

Don't attempt to control this at the connector or thread pool level, its not possible.

Instead, consider using the [QoSFilter (Quality of Service Filter)](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.4.x/qos-filter.html).

This lets you set the specific endpoint resource (your specific servlet that is performing these long running events) to only have a limited set of resources, leaving all other requests to process without the limitations you imposed via the filter.